# Ускорение передачи данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Как можно ускорить передачу данных из MySQL.
Какие настройки влияют на это, если влияют, и верно ли я понимаю это время, как время передачи данных а не их подготовку?(в скобках, network)

```
/* Найденные строки: 3,049  Предупреждения: 0  Длительность  1 запрос: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.172 sec. network) */
/* Найденные строки: 14,335  Предупреждения: 0  Длительность  1 запрос: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.687 sec. network) */
/* Найденные строки: 14,335  Предупреждения: 0  Длительность  1 запрос: 0.015 sec. (+ 0.672 sec. network) */
```

Explain запроса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD1. Проверил так же, на тех же данных и на том же железе на MariaDB, Разницы нет, длительность та же. Версия MySQL 5.6, Версия MariaDB 10.1

UPD2. https://yadi.sk/i/xHcZd48tJq4AYQ Оранжевым - запросы.

UPD3. Выяснил кто именно тормозит(видимо это я). Причина была в функции.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `ShowAsTime`(`InTime` INT) RETURNS varchar(10) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  if(ISNULL(@FormatDate))THEN
    SET @FormatDate='%Y-%m-%d';
  END IF;
  return IF(InTime>0,from_unixtime(InTime,@FormatDate),'---');
END
```

Теперь вопрос, почему выполнение функции записывалось на время передачи данных?

Comment: Ну, если скорость интернета 100 мегабит в секунду, то за 0.6 секунд передаётся примерно 8 мегабайт данных, а это примерно 600 байт на одну строку таблицы. Если данных в одной строке много, то это похоже на абсолютно нормальную скорость, которую можно увеличить только покупкой более дорогого интернета

Comment: @andreymal Вес передаваемых данных на 14к строк данных ~ 5МБайт, 
Соединение с сетью 1ГБит, но это не играет роли, все действия внутри одной машины идут.

Comment: "Причина была в функции" - к сожелению, телепаты, которые знают, о какой функции речь, в отпуске

Comment: @andreymal Т.е. ваш вопрос можно трактовать как "для некоторых функций норма поведения выдавать свое время выполнения как время передачи данных", текст функции добавил.

Comment: Т.е. после всех поисков у меня нет вопросов "почему эта функция тормозит", у меня вопрос: Почему это время записывалось на время передачи данных, а не на время выполнения запроса?

Comment: Кем записывалось? Какой-то статистико-глялелкой? вероятно кроме автора этой гляделки ответа больше никто не знает :)

Comment: @NewView Гляделось это через "MySQL Query browser" и HediSQL.., вопрос в другом, почему SQL сервер не записывает это во время выполнения запроса.. Выходит что вся пост обработка ведется уже после "извлечения" данных, в момент их передачи?

Comment: Подозреваю, что все еще печальнее. Я еще ни разу в show processlist не видел, что бы запрос из состояния 'sending data' возвращался обратно в 'executing'. И в этом 'sending data' он находится когда на самом деле ничего не передает, а ожидает пока на диске будет найдена следующая строка, если таблица большая это может занять много времени. Так что временем передачи скорее всего стоит считать время между получением первой строки результата и окончанием запроса, а это время получения всех последующих строк, включая вычисление всех функций

Comment: Вот запросы с группировкой и сортировкой,  в случаях когда они идут не по индексу, сначала выполняются полностью, а потом начинается передача, там картина может быть иной. Я для оценки реального времени выполнения запроса использую обычно `(select count(*) from (проверяемый-запрос) x` он сначала на стороне mysql все выполнит, посчитает кол-во записей в результате и вернет, время передачи будет нулевым, а время выполнения - это то, сколько ему действительно надо на получение всех строк

Comment: @Mike, вот за эту информацию спасибо, т.е. фактически время выполнения которое он у меня показует это чисто выборка индексов(все связи выборки и фильтры чисто по индексам идут).
Но тогда вопрос, новый возникает, from_unixtime - реально настолько медленная или у меня что то с настройками? время(общее, формирование + передача) - когда использую from_unixtime - порядка 0,5сек, без from_unixtime - 0.2сек.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Провел эксперимент: `select count(1) from (select from_unixtime(1,'%Y-%m-%d') from big_table limit 1000000) x` время 620ms, если параметр с форматом даты не передавать - то 450ms. А если вместо from_unixtime просто '1' - то 280ms. Да, функция притормаживает. правда я все таки миллион строк брал, а у вас только 15 тыс. Так что не знаю откуда у вас такая разница

Comment: @Mike, ну вызовов функции у меня получается 60к на 15к строк(несколько дат). Да может быть конечно тормоза именно на этой тестовой машине... все тесты веду на виртуалке достаточно слабой, чтоб на продакшн потом тормоза случайно не впустить....

Как бы сказать, 0.2-0.5 сек на такой запрос не критично, просто боюсь думать что будет как только база станет рабочей, там 200-300к записей а не 15к, да запрос 200к записей крайне редкое событие, в основном 2-5к записей будет запрашиватся, очень не хотел формировать отчеты в отложеном режиме для всех данных...

Comment: @Mike, благодарю за советы, проблемма локализована =) функция не причем, на виртуалке оперативки свободной маловато для таких джоинов как у меня в запросах были, странность в том что без from_unixtime - всё работает на ура, а с ней не влазиет в память и уходит в использование диска... п.с. на мысль навел ваш запрос...

Comment: @Mike
select count(1) from (select from_unixtime(1,'%Y-%m-%d') from big_data join big_data data2 limit **1 000 000**) ;
Затронуто строк: 0  Найденные строки: 1  Предупреждения: 0  Длительность  1 запрос: **2.859 sec**. 

select count(1) from (select from_unixtime(1,'%Y-%m-%d') from big_data join big_data data2 limit **100 000**) ;
Затронуто строк: 0  Найденные строки: 1  Предупреждения: 0  Длительность  2 запросов: **0.078 sec.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема локализована.
На машине на которой проводились тесты не хватало памяти для выполнения запроса внутри ОЗУ, запрос попадал на жесткий диск и появлялись тормоза.
Причем не помещался результат только при использовании функции from_unixtime, что усложнило поиск проблемы и некоторые непонимания(грешил что проблема именно в функции).

Так же время выполнения запроса которое возвращал SQL было временем фильтрации по индексам а не временем на вытаскивание всех данных.
Для подсчета реального времени затраченного на запрос воспользовался советом **@Mike**

```
select count(*) from (проверяемый-запрос) any_table
```

Время выполнения этого запроса полностью совпадало с "временем передачи" + "временем выполнения" проверяемого запроса, так что да, MySQL "слегка" врет о времени выполнения запроса.